# parse an unknown size string

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read an unknown size string from a text file and I used this code :

```
ifstream inp_file;
char line[1000] ;
inp_file.getline(line, 1000);
```

but I don't like it because it has a limit (even I know it's very hard to exceed this limit)but I want to implement a better code which reallocates according to the size of the coming string .

Comment: Why not use `std::string` for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [following](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) are some of the available options:

```
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim );
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );
```

Comment: is and str will have a fixed size and I want a solution that reallocates according to the size of input .

Comment: @Ahmed, these functions would do that unil string::max_size() elements are read.

Comment: @Ahmed: If you use std::getline() and std::string then the only practical limit is available memory. Are you having lines bigger than that? :)

Comment: It worked fine . I was missing the difference between this getline and the other one but now I understood.

Answer (score 2):

One of the usual idioms for reading unknown-size inputs is to read a chunk of known size inside a loop, check for the presence of more input (i.e. verify that you are not at the end of the line/file/region of interest), and extend the size of your buffer.  While the getline primitives may be appropriate for you, this is a very general pattern for many tasks in languages where allocation of storage is left up to the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at using [re2c](http://ttp://re2c.org/) which is a flexible scanner for parsing the input stream? In that way you can pull in any sized input line without having to know in advance... for example using a regex notation

```
^.+$
```

once captured by re2c you can then determine how much memory to allocate...

Comment: Okay, I suppose you cam do this. But sounds like massive overkill given that a solution is in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [memory-mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) in boost::iostreams.

Comment: Memory mapping doesn't help you here. You'd still need to know the size of the file to map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late to answer now, but just for documentation purposes, another way to read an unknown sized line would be to use a wrapper function. In this function, you use `fgets()` using a local buffer.

1. Set last character in the buffer to `'\0'`
2. Call `fgets()`
3. Check the last character and see if it's still `'\0'`

   - If it's not `'\0'` and it's not `'\n'`, implies not finished reading a line yet. Allocate a new buffer and copy the data into this new buffer and go back to step (1) above.
   - If there is already an allocated buffer, call `realloc()` to make it bigger. Otherwise, you are done. Return the data in an allocated buffer.

This was a tip given in my algorithms lecture.